# Change values of keys in json python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a problem with my python code. I have an already existing xml file, which has a structure like that:

```json
{
    "meta": {
        "date": "titel",
        "updated": "datum",
        "name": "schulname",
        "changes": {
            "classes": "aenderungk",
            "teachers": "aenderungl"
        },
        "unavailable": {
            "teachers": "abwesendl",
            "rooms": "abwesendr"
        },
...
```

My python code should now change the values of the keys. My code is following:

```py
def json_handler(self):
        with open("cache/pla.json", "r") as jsonFile:
            data = json.load(jsonFile)

        # update all meta values/informations
        data["meta"]["date"] = self.date
        data["meta"]["updated"] = self.updatet
        data["meta"]["name"] = self.school_name
        data["meta"]["changes"]["classes"] = self.classes_with_changes
        data["meta"]["changes"]["teachers"] = self.teachers_with_changes
        data["meta"]["unavailable"]["teachers"] = self.away_teacher
        data["meta"]["unavailable"]["rooms"] = self.unav_rooms

        with open("cache/pla.json", "w") as jsonFile:
            json.dump(data, jsonFile)
```

But I'm only getting this error:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zlelo/Documents/gi/socket/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    XML.parse_xml(value)
  File "/Users/zlelo/Documents/gi/socket/src/parse.py", line 64, in parse_xml
    self.json_handler()
  File "/Users/zlelo/Documents/gi/socket/src/parse.py", line 83, in json_handler
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/json/__init__.py", line 179, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/json/encoder.py", line 432, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/json/encoder.py", line 406, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/json/encoder.py", line 406, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/json/encoder.py", line 439, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Element is not JSON serializable
```

Thanks for every help!

Comment: It looks like some of your data is of type `Element`, and not a string. We can't know which, as you didn't provide the relevant code. Check all your data (`self.date` and so on)

Comment: The error occurs when writing new json into a file (`json.dump`). One of the new values can not be represented as `str`, hence the error.

Comment: fixed, problem was that some values aren't strings. thanks

Comment: Rather than note this in a comment, please provide an answer to your question and then note it as accepted.  In this way we all can benefit from this knowledge.